# Split the get the value using java

Tags: java

I have a reply message in a `String` and I want to split it to extract a value.

My String reply message format is:

```
REPLY(MSGID,15,ABC024049364194,SERVICE,10,CREATE,...);
```

My requirement is to get the value `ABC024049364194` from the above string format.

I tried using this code, but it hasn't worked:

```
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(",", 5); 

for (String a : arrOfStr) 
    System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: If you split the `String` by comma, you have to fetch the correct index afterwards. As far as I can see, it will be on index 2, so do `String[] arr = str.split(","); System.out.println(arr[2]);`

Comment: Define "it hasn't worked". Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. That said, if you have a *general* need to do this, regex isn't always the best solution.

Comment: Hi, what means `it hasn't worked` ? Please describe the behavior or the error which you are getting, from the first look you are on the right way, and if you want only ABC.. value, then you need token as on the second index `[2]`, indexing is from zero, so first `[0]` is `REPLY(MSGID`, `[1] 15`, `[2] ABC024049364194`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "REPLY(MSGID,15,ABC024049364194,SERVICE,10,CREATE,...)";
        String code = str.split(",")[2];
        System.out.println(code);

    }
```

Will work if your code is always after 2 coma

Answer (score 2):

If you split the String, you will simply need to access the token at index 2.

```
// <TYPE>(<ARGUMENTS>)
String message = "REPLY(MSGID,15,ABC024049364194,SERVICE,10,CREATE);";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\((.+)\\)").matcher(message);
if (m.find()) {
    String type = m.group(1);
    String[] arguments = m.group(2).split(",");
    System.out.println(type + " = " + arguments[2]); // REPLY = ABC024049364194
}
```